# info.plist adding a key

Tags: xcode, info.plist

Very simple question: How do I add this to info.plist? There's multiple info.plist files and all I can see is how to add a row.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have multiple targets, each target has a separate PList file with name `[TARGET-NAME]-Info.plist`.

You can add this by clicking the plus icon, then write `NSAppTransportSecurity` under "key" and choose type to be a dictionary. Then open it (arrow on the left should be facing down) and click the plus icon of that row, this will add a new entry **under** the `NSAppTransportSecurity` entry. Now you should write `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` at the newly created entry and choose it to be a boolean with value `YES`.

If you're editing the file with an external editor, you can just paste the above code before the last `</plist>` tag.