# The app is not showing on full screen on iPhone but is running fine on the simulator

Tags: ios, iphone

[image][image]The app is completely visible on the full screen in the simulator but does not show up completely when I run it on the device. Here with attaching the screen shots for consideration.
[image: Simulator image]

[image: iPhone image]

Comment: have you use autolayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a splash screen. It will solve your issue. The top & bottom black color is because you didn't added a splash screen. Add it & it will return to a full screen view. This happened because you have migrated the project which developed in an older version of xcode

Comment: I have already added a splash screen in the app but it is not showing up on the iPhone while it can be seen in the simulator.

Comment: Did you added it in launchScreen.storyboard file

Comment: Assests.xcassests file has a option of launch image I added the splash image there with varying pixel sizes as 2x etc.

Comment: @AashimaAnand If you didn't use launchScreen, Go to your Target's settings and choose General, then App Icons and Launch Images. Now set "Launch Screen File" to your "main.storyboard"

Comment: The screen has become full but the splash screen is not shown

Comment: Are you sure you added all required splash screens?

Comment: yes I am using iPhone 7 tell what dimensions are required

Comment: Evenif you are using iPhone 7, you should add all the required splash screens. You need to add all the images with sizes specified in https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/

Comment: Im not sure, why it is not coming. still plz try launchscreen.storyBoard for displaying launch screen instead of assets. It might help you

Answer (score 1):

A solution for your case

You need to add splash screen **@1x (Image for non retina display, don't put @1x), @2x, @3x** of all devices, and check this 100% your issue will be fixed.

i.e

```
splashscreen.jpg (@1x, Don't need @1x for non retina display)
splashscreen@2x.jpg
splashscreen@3x.jpg
```

Please check splash screen size in this link

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/

If still your issue not fixed please let me know or check above link.

## Update :

1. Please check **Launch screen interface file base name** in **info.plist**
   [image]
2. Please check In General Tab and check
   [image]

Comment: I am attaching a screen shot for he launch images I have added.

Comment: Ok, Now delete your app from your iPhone and install / run again. Many time i face this issue.

Comment: If you use SplashScreen.jpg then remove "LaunchScreen.storyboard" in your project.

Comment: yes I have done the same but still the launch screen image is not shown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148885/discussion-between-vivek-and-aashima-anand).

Answer (score 0):

What have you done to make the app FullScreen?
Maybe this will help:
Add the UIRequiresFullScreen key to your Xcode project’s Info.plist file and apply the Boolean value YES

Info.plist is one of the file below the Main.storyboard or viewController.swift
[image]

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608826/what-is-the-impact-of-the-requires-full-screen-option-in-xcode-for-an-iphone-o)

Comment: I am not able to get what you said. Can you please dictate me the steps?

Comment: Edited. Try adding the key.

Comment: I am attaching a screen shot I am getting that add button(+)

Comment: Hey, are you having problem with adding the key?
Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866136/info-plist-adding-a-key

Comment: You have to click the add button next to Information Property List, and type UIRequiresFullScreen, and set the boolean value to TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

You need try following solutions.

-> Add Launch Images and select in setting.
[image]

-> Add Launch screen storyboard and select it as **Launch screen file** in Setting.

[image]

Comment: you need to add image with this name in your project. This is works as your initial resolution of screen.

Comment: launch screen is not visible

Comment: when not appearing . if your have selected launch screen then remove app from device and try again.

Comment: or see this tutorial which i have added before edit my answer . : https://useyourloaf.com/blog/retina-4-support/

Answer (score 0):

[image]This happened only because of the splash screen for (Size 640 x 1136 ).

When you will add this size of splash screen this issue will solve.

If you already added then, i would suggest you to recheck the Size of your splash screen.

You have to check your image size only no need to do something else.

Please do one thing uncheck your iOS 6 or Prior from Assets.xcassets.
You can check it in this image.
[image]

Comment: the size 640*1136 is creating a new image in the folder as soon as I drag drop it

Comment: Which XCode version you are using @AashimaAnand

Comment: 8.3.1 @Parvendra Singh