# How do I set "NSHighResolutionCapable Info.plist property" to YES in macOS bigsur

Tags: c, xcode, macos, sdl-2

I was trying to make a 2D game in C in Xcode using SDL2. It failed to create a window and upon reading the documentation it said that "NSHighResolutionCapable Info.plist property to YES" in macOS. I'd like to know how to set that.

I've given the link for the documentation
http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow

Comment: Does this answer your question? [info.plist adding a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866136/info-plist-adding-a-key)

Answer (score 0):

The `Info.plist` is a file, and it is a part of your application bundle. It is not something that you would set using code. If you are using Xcode to make your project, then the Info.plist file is just an ordinary file you can edit.

There should be some Info.plist file in your project, although it may be named differently (like MyCoolGame-Info.plist). If it does not exist, it’s possible that you are not building an application bundle target.

If you want to enable Retina support, pass the `SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI` flag to SDL_CreateWindow.